# How to Listen for Events in children components in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, dom-events, eventemitter

I want to implement an event listener from parents to children components in my React Native app, I'm using a StackNavigator as a router.

How can I listen for events occurred in the top/parent components?

Comment: You can post a questions and answer yourself, don't answer in the question.

Answer (score 19):

Simply use React Native's `DeviceEventEmitter`.Emit your event from parent component like below:

```
DeviceEventEmitter.emit('eventKey', {name:'John', age:23});
```

and listen event in children component

```
componentDidMount(){
      //add listener
      this.eventListener = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('eventKey',this.handleEvent);
}

handleEvent=(event)=>{
 //Do something with event object
}

componentWillUnmount(){
      //remove listener
      this.eventListener.remove();
}
```

Comment: I like it, much better than passing the variable through screenProps of the StackNavigator. Thanks!

Comment: An important thing is to also make sure to remove the listener on the `componentWillUnmount()` event. This should be marked as an answer

Answer (score 2):

The best approach instead of using an EventEmitter with my current experience (7 months later this question) is using Redux as the state holder, you can create the variables that will pass the message through the components parent-children and then connect the component to get the variables (state) changes immediately it happens.

I decided to use [Rematch](https://github.com/rematch/rematch) that is a minified version of Redux and I have got very good results. It forced me to remove all my EventEmitters and use the dispatching methods to update variables (states) that will be updated in the connected components.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way:

1) Create listener at your app.js (Initial starting file):
Example:

```
(new NativeEventEmitter()).addListener('loggedIn',() => {
        setAuth(true);
    });
```

2) Just emit from any child: `(new NativeEventEmitter()).emit('loggedIn');`

Hope it will be useful to someone!)

Comment: Thanks. Its working ! now I can receive events from any nested components through out the app.

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching in how to emit and listen events from a Parent component to a Child component in React Native, after trying different ways I think that it could be good to share how I have got it working.

In your parent component (App.js in my case), import the EventEmitter lib:

```
import EventEmitter from 'EventEmitter';
```

Create a variable instance of the Event Emitter:

```
export default class App extends Component {

...

  componentWillMount() {
    this.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  }

...

}
```

Then, when something happens emit the event:

```
this.eventEmitter.emit('Event-Name', {args});
```

As I'm using a ***StackNavigator*** as a router I have to pass my ***eventEmitter*** variable to the children views:

```
const routes = {
  ChildView1: {
    screen: ChildComponent1
  },
  ChildView2: {
    screen: ChildComponent2
  },
  ...
};

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    ...routes,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'ChildView1',
    headerMode: 'none',
  /*
   * Use modal on iOS because the card mode comes from the right,
   * which conflicts with the drawer example gesture
   */
    mode: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'modal' : 'card',
  }
);

/* Here is the magic for the children views */

render(){
  return (
    <AppNavigator screenProps={this.eventEmitter} />
  );
}
```

Ok, now we have available our event listener for the children views, let's make a call in one of our children components:

```
export default class ChildComponent1 extends Component {

  ComponentWillMount(){

    this.eventEmitter = this.props.screenProps;

    this.eventEmitter.addListener('Event-Name', ()=>{

      // Do something

    });

  }

  ...

}
```

This is how I have done my event listener for child component, I hope it helps someone else. If you have a better implementation please share/comment it.

Comment: Another method which I think may work. You can save parent component's event in the local state and then pass it to Child Component as props so whenever an event occurs, it will change the state in Parent and Child component's `componentWillReceiveProps` method will be called where you can handle it.

Answer (score -1):

Having an Event Emitter can probably get a bit messy when tracking where the event came from or where it's being listened.

Just like you pass the event emitter down to the child via `screenProps={this.eventEmitter}` (which is what you are essentially doing), why not just pass an actual function your child can use to initiate actions on its parent. That'd probably be the most react way to do things.

It probably not is ideal to add an additional event listener as it will affect performance at some point.

Comment: It sounds good, but I can't get it working. I have passed a null parent variable then in the child view set a function to this, but when I try to call it on the parent it still being null/undefined.

Answer (score -1):

I have followed OPs idea of using redux and it worked well for me. Here is the code...

actionTypes.js:

```
export const TRIGGER_REQUEST_SUBMIT = "TRIGGER_REQUEST_SUBMIT";
export const ACKNOWLEDGE_REQUEST_SUBMIT = "ACKNOWLEDGE_REQUEST_SUBMIT";
```

eventActions.js:

```
import * as types from "./actionTypes";

export function triggerRequestSubmit() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch({ type: types.TRIGGER_REQUEST_SUBMIT });
  };
}

export function acknowledgeRequestSubmit() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch({ type: types.ACKNOWLEDGE_REQUEST_SUBMIT });
  };
}
```

eventReducer.js:

```
import * as types from "../actions/actionTypes";
import initialState from "./initialState";

export default function eventReducer(state = initialState.event, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.TRIGGER_REQUEST_SUBMIT:
      return { ...state, shouldSubmitRequest: true };
    case types.ACKNOWLEDGE_REQUEST_SUBMIT:
      return { ...state, shouldSubmitRequest: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to register reducer in your root-reducer/index.js in reducers

initialState.js:

```
export default {
  event: {
    shouldSubmitRequest: false
  }
};
```

Usage in child(Use redux to connect & get shouldSubmitRequest via state, acknowledgeRequestSubmit via dispatch):

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldSubmitRequest) {
      console.log("shouldSubmitRequest triggered in Request");
      acknowledgeRequestSubmit();
    }
  }, [shouldSubmitRequest]);
```

In parent call triggerRequestSubmit(); (connect to redux to get that method)

Comment: Alternatively ContextAPI can also be used. I haven't tried it and would love to see someone explain the way to do it.